# finding a variable that exist in the dataset

Tags: variables, dataset

So i have tried to search and look for this answer and cannot figure it out.

I have tried searching my dataset by "year" which is an actual variable and another variable in the dataset too "ahe" (all lowercase) but it reads

> **cpi <- 156.9*(year==1996) + 237.0*(year==2015)** (this code is the professors which for him works)
>   Error: object 'year' not found

Then I tried: **cpi <- 156.9*(CPS96_15_1_$ahe[CPS96_15_1_$year==2015]) + (CPS96_15_1_$ahe[CPS96_15_1_$year==1996])**
In the latter, both CPS... portions of 1995 and 2015 worked for prior equations.

I have used the year variable earlier along as the "ahe variable". I reread the csv file, checked the working directory and made sure through the summary it came up which it did:

> names(CPS96_15_1_)
>   [1] "year"     "ahe"      "bachelor" "female"   "age"

May anyone help please?
Thanks!

Comment: Hi Wendolyn. It's difficult to help you with this question (is this R?). Have a look here: https://reprex.tidyverse.org/

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out through the attach function attach(name of csv file)